# Creating a nickname from other columns by migration, laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, database-migration, laravel-migrations

I have a table with users, which includes fields for "first name" and "last name" and I need to create a "nick" field during migration and fill them in by creating a string of lowercase letters from the firstname and lastname without spaces.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to auto-complete this column with other columns.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: *"the firstname and lastname **without spaces.**"* - Please be aware that both first and last names _can_ contain spaces. If you're generating the nickname from existing first and last name values, you'll need to handle that possibility 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a raw query to update the column after it's created that will grab the two columns, concatenate them, and convert them to lowercase.

```
  Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
       $table->string('nick')->nullable();
  });

  DB::query("UPDATE users SET nick = LOWER(CONCAT(first_name, last_name))";
```

Comment: Wouldn't this database query update all previous users' nicknames with every new user created?

Comment: No, as long as this code is inside of the migration, it will only run when the migration runs.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the nickname should not be unique, you can also listen to the `created` event inside `User` model like this:

```
class User extends Model
{
  /**
  * The "booted" method of the model.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  protected static function booted()
  {
    static::created(function ($user) {
        $user->nickname = Str::lower($user->first_name . $user->last_name);
        $user->save();
    });
  }
}
```

More on `events` here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures